# How to access a specific user's model data as admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm creating a simple model form that is only available to staff. It has a user selection dropdown list populated by models.py `user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`.

On submit I need my view to look up the selected user from the form and return the data in the models for that user (from the built-in Django database). How would I go about doing this?

I have searched here and the recommended articles, but they all appear to be for accessing a model as the logged-in user. Here is a screenshot of the form and my code:

[image: get a selected user's model data]

**models.py**

```
class GetData(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**forms.py**

```
class DataRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = GetData
        fields = ['user']
```

**Views.py**

```
@login_required
def data_form(request):
    if request.user.is_staff == True:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = DataRequestForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = request.POST["user"]
                print("Form is Valid")
                print(user) 
                # How to access that user's model data here?
```

Comment: you mean you want to select `x user` and then on click you want first name last name and all the details of that user?

Comment: So on click to have all associated model data with that user. So for example, they complete an application form in another model say `class Application(models.Model)`. I would like to access that model for them too.

Comment: You don't need a model (GetData) for that (for accessing the user data) unless you want to save the data which is already saved in Database. Why did you create a model to retrieve the user data ?

Comment: You can get the value of the choice field using `JS` and trigger an event (can be ajax call to the database) on `Get their Model data` button click to attach the chosen name with the URL to call the view which will retrieve data based on username.

Comment: @Lars Yes, I am trying to retrieve the data and do something else with it. I need to access the data within an application form for each user `class Application(models.Model)`.

Comment: How do you intend to save it in the `GetData` model ? I mean Other Models will retrieve user data like : `Username  -> user_1`, `first_name -> First Name`, `second_name -> Second Name`, so Do you want to create every field in `GetData` model which are in other models ?

Comment: @Lars I actually just want to retrieve 5 fields worth of data from other models using `GetData` not save it. The reason I want to access the data this way is for staff members to create a task with the submit button (which I know how to write in the view after I get those 5 fields). `GetData`'s purpose is just to retrieve each user.

Comment: Are you using `HTML` render or some API to interact with `FrontEnd` ?

Comment: @Lars It will be a Google API, basically retrieving and sending the specific user data from 5 date fields to create-events in Google Calendar API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first get user by id then get model details using that retrieved user.

views.py

```
@login_required
def data_form(request):
    if request.user.is_staff == True:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = DataRequestForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = request.POST["user"]
                print("Form is Valid")
                print(user) 
                
                # getting user data by id.
                get_user = get_object_or_404(User, id=user)

                get_another_model_data = SecondModel.objects.filter(user=get_user)

                # perform or save the data here
```

Comment: This worked and I tested it with `print(get_another_model_data.values())`